# Ruby on Rails equivalent in python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I've no experience with Ruby but I heard that Ruby on Rails is a great framework to build websites super fast. What's its equivalent in python? If there's none, which of the existing python website building frameworks come closer to it?

Comment: I did google and knew of django and others upfront and in fact have written some basic stuff in it too. But I still wanted to hear the popular opinion. Afterall this is a community, isn't it

Comment: Thanks for the link Steven. Will keep that in mind. FYI, a quick search of Python vs Ruby in this forum brings up a lot of threads - contrary to what's mentioned in that link. But in any case, I get it and thanks for educating me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is considered to be the Python equivalent to Rails. Both [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and Rails focus on rapid development.

To get you started, here are some related resources:

- Official Django Website: http://www.djangoproject.com/
- Official Documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/
- A **great** book on Django development: http://www.djangobook.com/

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby on Rails equivalent for Python is Django.

It's a:

> High-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and
>   clean, pragmatic design.

I personally recommend [Python Web Development with Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132356139), as it is a  good book for learning about Django (obviously).


You can learn more about Django, here: https://www.djangoproject.com/